# ASP.NET MVC in vNext and System.Web Dependency

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I was reading [These notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/05/12/the-next-generation-of-net-asp-net-vnext.aspx#_ASP.NET_vNext)

> ASP.NET vNext includes updated versions of MVC, Web API, Web Pages, SignalR and EF. The key improvement with these frameworks is that **MVC, Web API and Web Pages have been merged into a single programming model**. For example, there’s now unified controller and routing concepts between all three. You can now have a single controller that returns both MVC views and formatted Web API responses, on the same HTTP verb.

Knowing that Web API and SignalR does not have a dependency with System.Web, thus one can self-host them with Katana/Owin, does anyone know what's the story with MVC in the vNext? Does it still depend on System.Web or are we finally going to ditch it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for speculation about unreleased software

Comment: @alroc The preview has already been released this year and anyone running it can relatively easily verify this dependency. Keep in mind, the question is about vNext, not the "release version" that is still yet to come.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the answer here:

[ASP.NET vNext - Everything you need to know in 4 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_XmpFGQ37NA#t=157)

> "However the biggest change that's coming with ASP.NET vNext is severing its ties with System.Web and moving to the new Owin hosting model..."

Furthermore...

> "...allows you to take any web host such as IIS or self-hosting within an console app"

Comment: There is no more System.Web in this new stack

Comment: @dfowler +1 for just saying that aloud \o/

Comment: @davidfowl how about MVC 6 on Full FX, I suppose Full FX will still ship System.Web. Would it be possible to have, for instance, a custom view engine that depends on System.Web for custom (build|virtual path) providers?

Comment: You can totally use the APIs, but MVC 6 has no relation to System.Web or MVC 5 in a binary compatible way. You probably spend tons of time writing a shim to convert from one to the other, but for understanding sake, treat them as 2 different frameworks.